# PHP hazardous return on exec() function

Tags: php, windows, shell-exec, netstat

this function produce nothing, anyone knows why ?

```
var_dump(shell_exec('netstat /?'));
```

it's the same problem with the exec() version.

however this code works well

```
var_dump(shell_exec('dir /?));
```

Comment: Perhaps this code isn't running at all. Have you configured PHP to display errors?

Comment: yes i think cause php usually display them, and at the time it's the lonely command who working as this

Comment: Are you positively sure that you are getting no output at all? Not even `NULL`?

Comment: i obtain '' exactly... nope sorry an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `-n` flag to the command:

```php
var_dump(shell_exec('netstat -n'));
```

Even better, with `exec()` you can also assign the output of the command to an array:

```php
exec('netstat -n', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: the command whit the 'netstat -n' parameter works it's not the problem and i know exec() (and it's the same like with shell_exec() ). but my problem is the ('netstat /?')  don't return any string... on the contrary 'dir /? ', or the 'help' or the 'ipconfig /?' have string return. so i don't understand what's the problem with 'netstat'

Answer (score 0):

[netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) with the `/?` switch does not print in the standard output (stdout) but in the standard error (stderr). Since your PHP code doesn't make any arrangement to capture stderr you only get the (empty) stdout. If you run PHP from command-line you should see stderr anyway but if you run PHP though a web server (which I presume is the case here) then stderr is discarded. However, that alone doesn't explain blank output since [shell_exec()](https://php.net/shell_exec) returns (emphasis mine):

> The output from the executed command or **`NULL` if** an error occurred or **the command produces no output**.

In any case, if you don't want to fiddle with [pipes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) you may just [redirect stderr to stdout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout):

```
var_dump(shell_exec('netstat /? 2>&1'));
```

Comment: i tried it and it seems stderr redirection don't works at all ^^. could you give me some little explain on how to deal with pipes ?

Comment: You must have some other problem located elsewhere. Not even var_dump() seems to produce the usual output. I've no idea.

Comment: i tried to use a dumper like the var-dumper component. but it's the same...